# Cannot find rxjs modules when using typescript/webpack build

Tags: typescript, webpack, rxjs

I'm trying to get rxjs to work within a typescript/webpack set up but after following the [installation guide](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html) and starting up the webpack dev server it says it cannot find the module. I've looked around but can't seem to anything that can point me to a solution for my problem.

Just to clarify I've run the following commands `npm install rxjs-es @types/es6-shim --save`.

To set up typescript/webpack bundle, I referred to their [installation guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/).

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [ 'babel-loader', 'ts-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};
```

index

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';


d3.select("body").append("span")
    .text("Hello, world!");

Rx.Observable.of(`Hello World`)
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Error message:

[image]

I've tried using both `rxjs` and `rxjs-es` packages, and renaming the import to `rxjs-es/Rx`

Not sure if I'm missing something here, as it was very simple to install d3.js in comparison to this.

If you need any more info please say, any help is much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me:

I started with the setup you describe, BUT changed the following:

- npm installed rxjs, not rxjs-es
- (EDIT) removed `@types/es6-shim`
- added `"moduleResolution": "node"` to tsconfig.json
- altered the import statement in `index.ts` as:

  ```
  import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
  ```

...and it worked, both from within VSCode and from Webpack.

Comment: awesome - thanks! Also, having `@types/es6-shim` installed was unnecessary and threw a compiler error after using your solution. Just in case anyone else uses this

Comment: Ooops, yes I forgot: I too removed @types/es6-shim - adding to answer!